# What is the most reliable high-level language / library for non-blocking SSL sockets?

Tags: ssl, nonblocking

Everybody and their dog can write blocking socket code, but non-blocking is considerably harder. Add SSL into it, which even on protocol level brings complications into non-blocking processing, and you can get out of luck. Obviously, it can be done in C using direct OpenSSL calls, but that's get complicated and feels like reinventing the wheel. But higher level languages and libraries often have their non-blocking support buggy and unreliable.

I've already tried following:

- ruby with kgio. It included something CALLED kgio_monkey_ext which apparently disappeared from internet and was never documented. It didn't worked, it just kept blocking.
- perl with AnyEvent and Net::SSLeay. Mostly works, but occasionally lose some socket and occasionally blocks or rather hangs up. Also, I've found this article which describes some problems with Net::SSLeay's support for non-blocking sockets: http://devpit.org/wiki/OpenSSL_with_nonblocking_sockets_%28in_Perl%29 which may or may not be related.

My motivation is to write sort of SSL connect proxy, which accepts requests from clients in form on server address and port, connects to them with SSL/TLS and then proxies the traffic between the plain client and SSL server, while responding to other requests in parallel.

Would there be any language and/or library which is better suited for such task than with AnyEvent and Net::SSLeay, in terms of better reliability (not blocking, not leaking memory, not leaking sockets), clearer documentation/examples and how much I would need to write in it?

Alternatively, is this already implemented somewhere, in form I can modify to support the request protocol I need?

Or should I try harder with perl?